# Exporting Projects in Xcode (Get xarchive File)

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I am trying to create an xarchive file for my application - but i have been googling it and i cannot seem to find how to actually create one in Xcode 7.

Does anyone know how i can export my profile to become an xarchive file?

I have attached my iPhone to the project and selected the phone > gone to product > archive > but the options are all blanked out.

Thank you

Comment: Well that's how you do it.  Perhaps you have the wrong target selected?

Comment: Do you have a distribution certificate / provision?

Comment: Try to go to edit scheme, then click Build on the left, and make sure that the archive option is selected on the last column to the right

Comment: Thanks, but how do you edit schemes? @GuyDaher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that Generic iOS Device is selected at the top

[image]

If it still does not work, try to go to edit scheme, then click Build on the left, and make sure that the archive option is selected on the last column to the right.

[image: Edit Scheme]

[image]